# Must I award a non-answer with a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I offered a bounty to a [question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36115650/getting-corners-using-gpuimageharriscornerdetectionfilter). Only one answer has been given, and it's an obvious non-answer (doesn't address the question).

Can I prevent this non-answer receiving the bounty?

Comment: No, you can't do anything against it if there's only one answer.

Comment: The answer won't get a bounty in your case (I just looked at it) because the answer doesn't have enough score. As long as you don't _manually_ award the bounty, an answer must have been posted after the bounty started _and_ have a score of 2 or more to receive _half_ the bounty.

Comment: Had this happen. I downvoted the answer, voted to delete, and left a comment detailing why it was a nonsense non-answer asking the poster to delete and, failing that, for others to downvote and vote to delete the answer.  Bountied questions get eyes, and often times people will be glad to help rid you of crappy answers.

Comment: (example of the above http://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJUe.png)

Comment: For the record, this _is_ an answer. It's just a really, really bad one. Look up some meta posts about what "not an answer" means because this is not it!

Comment: All of you - thanks a lot for the clarifications - just wish my real question got this much attention :)

Comment: Given SO moderator BradLarson is the creator of GPUImage, odds are posting here will get you the attention you need eventually :)  Good luck.

Comment: Ha, figures this would be asked while I was on the road at a tradeshow. Seems to have worked out, with a correct answer being provided.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To quote the [Bounty FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> **What happens if I feel my question is still unanswered?**
>
> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period, if the
>   bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be
>   awarded automatically.
>
> [...], if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is
>   awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be
>   eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a **score of at least +2**
> - The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter
>
> If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any
>   answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.

So you just have to make sure that the answer doesn't get upvoted. Then the bounty will not be awarded and expires.

Comment: Downvotes + comment on the non-answer can help convince others that it is a poor answer not deserving of a bounty.

Comment: What does "the bounty **may be** awarded automatically" mean here?

Comment: @cad It is awarded automatically only if it fulfills the criteria.

Comment: @cad: Contrast it with _"the highest scoring **is** awarded half the bounty amount"_ — it's a dead cert that the bounty is awarded, when the criteria for doing so are satisfied. Your quoted use of "may be" simply allows for the _"If neither of these conditions apply, the bounty is not awarded to any answer"_ case. Hard to misinterpret, I should think?

Comment: *"make sure that the answer doesn't get upvoted"*, as far as I understand StackExchange system, this is not something that you can do, and it's this way on purpose. The only thing that you can do to this end is not to upvote it *yourself*. This sentence could benefit from rephrasing.

Answer (score 6):

Not necessarily.  From [How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.

So, if there's only one answer posted in the bounty period, it has to have a score of at least 2 (upvotes) in order for half the bounty to be awarded. You may be able to prevent it with a downvote, but other people may upvote the answer so that the bounty will still be awarded.

Answer (score 4):

If it's really an obvious non-answer, you should flag it as such. Presumably it will be deleted, and obviously once it's deleted it's not eligible for the bounty.

If the answer is actually an answer, just one that doesn't meet your expectations for the bounty, then you may have to give it the bounty depending on how it's received by the community, as explained in other answers.